# Why doesn't "helm install --dry-run" give me an error about a conflict but an actual "helm install" does?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I installed my app like this:

```sh
helm install my-app my-application/ --set externalName.namespace=app-layer
```

Checking the pods and services, everything installed correctly.

I then tried a `dry-run` expecting to get a conflict but it simply printed out the YAML and some info about the previous install.

```sh
helm install my-app my-application/ --set externalName.namespace=app-layer --dry-run
```

The above printed out:

```
NAME: my-app
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Dec 22 19:52:33 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
externalName:
  namespace: app-layer

COMPUTED VALUES:
#...elided by me...

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:
---
#...elided by me...
```

**However**, when I try to install I get this error:

```
Error: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
```

Why doesn't the dry run catch that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dry-run mode, the `availableName` check [explicitly stops](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/bfc575dec2f6ed5ce897c38d0d89b0fe936606c0/pkg/action/install.go#L421-L423) before actually checking if the name you've provided is in use.  You'll still get a complaint if you explicitly give an empty name or if the name is longer than 53 characters.

Practically, I tend to use `helm upgrade --install` instead of `helm install` most of the time, since that will work even if the chart is already installed.